# MySql Connector 6.8.2 RC, Entity Framework 6 and Code First

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I recently upgraded to Entity Framework 6 and installed the MySql 6.8.2 RC Connector as it stated there was support for EF6 Code First now.

*Keep in mind, prior to the upgrade my project was functioning fine running in connector 6.7.4 and EF 5.*

**I made the following changes to my web.config**

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

```
<connectionStrings>
<add providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="dbcontext" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=db; Uid=un; Pwd=pw;Convert Zero Datetime=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**I also added the following references (.net 4.5 versions)**

1. MySql.Data
2. MySql.Data.Entity.EF6
3. MySql.Web

The problem is - the moment the code calls the DBContext i receive:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Again - keep in mind that everything worked prior to the upgrade, so I know its not a code issue, however, maybe I didn't setup the web.config properly?

Also - you may ask, if it worked great prior to the upgrade, why upgrade? Well, supposedly EF6 and the new MySql connector solves some bugs I was running into - so I was hoping to implement it now, while its in development and by the time it moves to production (months from now) I should be able to load in the production version of the 6.8.x connector.

**Here is the stack trace in case it helps**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +85
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +332
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +67
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k) +63
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +260
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +89
System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +79
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +143
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +171
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +594
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +138
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +41
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +142
[edited].Global.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\edited\Global.asax.cs:47
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: aren't you suppose to report this as issue/bug at the project support site? since it's a RC, it's a beta.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is a new/diff way to set it up - i did however post this on the mysql forums as well. So if i get an answer there i'll update it here as well

Comment: What about a link to the question in the mysql forum?

Comment: @99823 Did you find out what was causing this issue for you?

Comment: I set web project as startup project, then it worked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a release candidate, and it's not indicated if the problem persisted in the final release.

Answer (score 27):

I had MySQL EF6 and Migrations up and working when everything was in one MVC project. I split it out into layers (Core[Interfaces/Entitites], Data, Services, and Web) and started getting the same error Loren mentioned.

Figured out that it wasn't picking up the connection string from the MVC app. Turns out that all I had to do was re-create the connection string within the App.config in my Data project (where the DbContext and mappings reside).

These are the steps I took to get everything working:

**Step 1)** Use NuGet to import *MySql.Data.Entities* (current version as of this post is 6.8.3.0)

**Step 2)** Add the following to *App.config* and/or *Web.config*:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; port=3306; Initial Catalog=mydb; uid=myuser; pwd=mypass;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

**Step 3)** Set up your DbContext to use MySql:

```
using MyApp.Core.Entities.Directory;
using MyApp.Data.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyApp.Data
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() : this("MyDB") { }
        public MyContext(string connStringName) : base(connStringName) {}
        static MyContext ()
        {
            // static constructors are guaranteed to only fire once per application.
            // I do this here instead of App_Start so I can avoid including EF
            // in my MVC project (I use UnitOfWork/Repository pattern instead)
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // I have an abstract base EntityMap class that maps Ids for my entities.
            // It is used as the base for all my class mappings
            modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(EntityMap<>).Assembly);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4)** Set the Default Project to your Data project in the Package Manager Console

**Step 5)** Use `enable-migrations`, `add-migration`, `update-database` like you normally would

Comment: I had a similar problem. When splitting things up I had to add my `connectionStrings` to both the `app.config` (Data project) and the `web.config`. The packagemanager console uses the app.config one and the mvc website uses the `web.config`

Comment: that is you can't use same code for Sql and Mysql: you have to tag your DbContext class ???

Comment: in fact you can by using `<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, mysql.data.entity.EF6">...</entityFramework>` in app.config instead of the class attribute.

Answer (score 5):

ContosoUniversity MVC5 + EF6 code first approach using MySQL example download:
http://www.nzmk.com/Blogs/BlogsView/tabid/83/EntryId/8/MVC5-EF6-ContosoUniversity-code-first-approach-using-MySQL.aspx

To start using Entity Framework 6 and Visual Studio 2013 it is necessary to install 
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.1 
MySQL Connector/Net 6.8.3 GA

MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.1 Beta can be downloaded with the following link: 
cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi

MySQL Connector/Net 6.8.3 GA 
dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

To start working with VS 2013 and EF 6

1. Uninstall old versions of MySQL for Visual Studio and Connector/Net
2. Install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.1
3. Install Connector/Net 6.8.3
4. Add the reference for MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, MySql.Web (Version 6.8.3.0) assemblies into the project. Depending on the .NET Framework used, the assembly is to be taken from either the v4.0 or the v4.5 folder).
5. Edit web.config or app.config

   > ```
   > <connectionStrings>
   >     <add name='SchoolContext' connectionString='Data Source=xxxxx;port=3306;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity;user id=root;password=xxxxxxxxx;' providerName='MySql.Data.MySqlClient'/>
   >  </connectionStrings>
   >  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType='MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'>
   >     <defaultConnectionFactory type='System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework'/>
   >     <providers>
   >       <provider invariantName='MySql.Data.MySqlClient' type='MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices,
   > ```
   >
   > MySql.Data.Entity.EF6' />
6. Edit SchoolContext.cs

   > ....
   >       using MySql.Data.Entity;
   >
   > ```
   > namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
   > {
   >   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
   >   public class SchoolContext : DbContext
   >   {
   >   ....
   >   }
   > }
   > ```
7. Edit Global.asax.cs

   > ......
   >       using MySql.Data.Entity;
   >
   > ```
   > namespace ContosoUniversity
   > {
   >     public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   >     {
   >         protected void Application_Start()
   >         {
   >             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   >             FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   >             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   >             BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
   >
   >             DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration());
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```